# Media queries in Picture source aren’t kicking in reliably when min-width is used for each source

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I’m using the following markup for my images:

```css
picture {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  display: block;
}

img {
  block-size: auto;
  display: block;
  max-inline-size: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(width < 672px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Small" />
  <source media="(width >= 672px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Medium" />
  <source media="(width >= 1056px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Large" />
  <source media="(width >= 1312px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=X-Large" />
  <source media="(width >= 1584px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max" />
  <source media="(width > 1784px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max+Plus" />
  <img alt="" height="1250" loading="eager" src="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Fallback" width="2500" />
</picture>
```

For some reason unknown to me only the `medium` image (`(width >= 672px)`) is being displayed at all breakpoints medium and above. The other larger sizes never kick in. I would expect these to work just like `min-width` in CSS, but the larger breakpoints don’t seem to override the first `>=` breakpoint, which is Medium.

I can be more explicit with my ranges:

```css
picture {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  display: block;
}

img {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  block-size: auto;
  display: block;
  max-inline-size: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(width < 672px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Small" />
    <source media="(width >= 672px) and (width < 1056px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Medium" />
    <source media="(width >= 1056px) and (width < 1312px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Large" />
    <source media="(width >= 1312px) and (width < 1584px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=X-Large" />
    <source media="(width >= 1584px) and (width < 1784px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max" />
    <source media="(width > 1784px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max+Plus" />
    <img alt="" height="1250" loading="eager" src="/images/examples/responsive-671.png" width="2500" />
</picture>
```

In which case the images load and render correctly, but this defeats the purpose of `min-width` queries. I don’t want users to have to supply images for all breakpoints.

---

**UPDATE**

Order seems to matter. If I reverse the order from largest breakpoint to smallest (instead of the reverse) it seems to work.

```css
picture {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  display: block;
}

img {
  block-size: auto;
  display: block;
  max-inline-size: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(width > 1784px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max+Plus" />
  <source media="(width >= 1584px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max" />
  <source media="(width >= 1312px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=X-Large" />
  <source media="(width >= 1056px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Large" />
  <source media="(width >= 672px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Medium" />
  <source media="(width < 672px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Small" />
  <img alt="" height="1250" loading="eager" src="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Fallback" width="2500" />
</picture>
```

Comment: I pasted your code into codepen to test it - it works there but not when testing here on Stackoverflow. Might be a caching issue with placehold.co in combination with strings passed? Try targeting "real" different image-files so you know if that's the case :)

Comment: Yeah, I only used placehold.co for my example here. Using real images I created locally, each different. Odd.

Comment: Order seems to matter here. In my first example above, if I reverse the order from largest breakpoint to smallest it works as expected.

Comment: Yep! This is the same where you set `sizes` attribute on an `img` tag. You start at the largest breakpoint. You may want to consider adding your **update** as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, order matters here. If I reverse the order of `<source />` tags from largest breakpoint to smallest (instead of the reverse) it seems to work.

Example:

```css
picture {
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  display: block;
}

img {
  block-size: auto;
  display: block;
  max-inline-size: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(width > 1784px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max+Plus" />
  <source media="(width >= 1584px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Max" />
  <source media="(width >= 1312px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=X-Large" />
  <source media="(width >= 1056px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Large" />
  <source media="(width >= 672px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Medium" />
  <source media="(width < 672px)" srcset="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Small" />
  <img alt="" height="1250" loading="eager" src="https://placehold.co/2000x1000?text=Fallback" width="2500" />
</picture>
```